# Java linked list - issues w 3 methods

Tags: java, list, linked-list

I am currently working on a linked list project but I am stumped on my last 3 methods, my removeWord(), concatenate() and doubleChar().. I was wondering if anyone one could give me some tips in what I am doing wrong.

```
class Node {
private char letter;
private Node next;
public Node(char ch, Node link) {
letter = ch;
next = link;
 }
public void setLetter(char letter) {
this.letter=letter;
 }
 public char getLetter() {

 return letter; 
 }
 public void setNext(Node next) {
 this.next=next;
 }
 public Node getNext() {

 return next;
 }
 }


 class Word {
 // instance variable pointing to the head of the linked list
 private Node head;

 // default constructor
 public Word() {
 head = null;
 }
 // copy constructor
 public Word(Word w) {
 this.head = copy(w.head);
 }
 private static Node copy(Node l){
 Node newL;
 if( l ==null){
    newL=null;

 }else{
    newL = new Node(l.getLetter(),copy(l.getNext()));
 }
 return newL;
 }

  // constructor from a String
  public Word( String s ) {
  Node pt;
  head = null;
  for( int i = s.length()-1; i >=0; i--){
  pt = new Node(s.charAt(i),head);
  head = pt;
  }

  }
 // for output purposes -- override Object version
 // no spaces between the characters, no linefeeds/returns

  @Override
  public String toString() {
  //s.charAt
  return toString(head);
 // return toString(head);
}

  private static String toString(Node L){
   String Word="";
   if (L == null){
    // do nothing 
  }
  else{
    Word = L.getLetter() + toString(L.getNext());
   // return the letter
   }
    return Word;
  }

  // remove the first occurrence of the Word w from this Word
  public void removeWord( Word w ) {
   head = removeWord(head,w);
  }


   private static Node removeWord(Node L, Word w)
  {

   if(L == null)
 {
    // do nothing

  }else if(L==w.head){
    L = L.getNext();

   }
 else {
    // remove the word

  L.setNext(removeWord(L.getNext(),w));
  }
    return L;

  }

  // concatenate a copy of s to the end of this Word
  public void concatenate( Word s ) {
  this.head = concatenate(head,s);

 }
 private static Node concatenate(Node L, Word s){  
 if( L==null){
  L = null;
 }
 else{
 L = new Node(L.getLetter(),concatenate(L.getNext(),s));
 L.setNext(concatenate(L.getNext(),s));// add to the end of the list
 } 
 return L;

  }

  // make a copy of every occurrence of ch in this Word
  // for example, if this Word is abbcbccb, doubleChar ( 'b' ) should
  // change the Word to abbbbcbbccbb
  public void doubleChar( char ch ) {
  head = doubleChar(head,ch);
  }
  public static Node doubleChar(Node L, char ch){
  if(L == null)
  {

  }

  else if(L.getLetter()==ch){

  }
  else{
    //double 
    L.setNext(doubleChar(L.getNext(),ch));
   }
    return L;
   }
```

Comment: It would be good to know what the current behavior of these methods is.

Comment: sorry about that my concatenation method is only printing out the first word for example 'abc' where as im trying to add another word to the end of it to make it 'abcdefg'. where as the removeword isn't removing the words and my double char is only printing it out 'abc' instead of 'aabc'

Comment: If you want other people to read your code, you need to indent it properly.